# Why is "Deny" used in Data Control Language?

Tags: sql

I newly started to learn basics of SQL and while I was searching about Data Manipulation Language, Data Control Language, Data Definition Language something didn't make sense.

As far as I understand, Data Control Language has 3 keywords: Grant, Deny, Revoke.

"Grant" allows the specified users to do certain things.
"Revoke" destroys any security clearance the specified users have.

However, what I don't understand is "Deny".

If users don't have a security clearance (Is there a special term computer science?) to a specific database at the beginning, why would the programmer who designs the database would "Deny" that user's clearance to that database? It doesn't make sense.

Could someone tell me why and where to use "Deny"?

Comment: Example: a user is put in a role and thus 'inherits' the role's permissions. But you may then want to deny the user permissions on a particular object that was granted by being in that role. `Deny`ing has precedence over anything that has been `Grant`ed.

Answer (score 5):

Deny - as in "deny access".

It means explicitly not allowing someone to do something. That's not the same as giving access and taking away access that grant and revoke do, respectively.

Consider that you may grant a group access to a schema, but for a sub-set of that group you want to deny access to a subset of the tables defined in the schema. "deny" gives you a way to do so.

Comment: Does it has same meaning as ACl in linux like you allow a user to do something but not an other specific thing?

Comment: @DavidLevel - grant is similar. Deny is specifically not letting access to a resource (they they may otherwise have access to).

Comment: So, basicly what "Deny" does is to "limit" someone's access to something.

Comment: Ok I though GRANT + DENY where like ACL, not only GRANT. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @user2552867 - yes, that's the use case.

Answer (score 1):

The DENY command can be used to explicitly prevent a user from receiving a particular permission.

This is helpful when a user may be a member of a role or group that is granted a permission and you want to prevent that user from inheriting the permission by creating an exception.